# What is the correct way to call patch from an OData client in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Following the OData samples created by the web api team, my controller has the following for supporting Patch:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Foo> item)
{
  var dbVersion = myDb.GetById(key);
  if(dbVersion == null)
    throw Request.EntityNotFound();

  item.Patch(dbVersion);
  myDb.Update(dbVersion);

  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

and using the auto-generated client (derived from `DataServiceContext`), I submit a patch request like this:

```
var foo = svcContainer.Foos.Where (f => f.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
foo.Description = "Updated Description";
svcContainer.UpdateObject(foo);
svcContainer.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PatchOnUpdate);
```

However, tracing the call in fiddler, I see that all other properties of Foo are serialized and sent to the service. Is that the correct behavior? I expected only the Id and Description to be sent over the wire. Also, if I debug the service method and call

`GetChangedPropertyNames` on item, all its property names are returned.

Should I be creating some sort of Delta instance on the client?

<strike>I understand the disconnected nature of the service and thus the service side does not have a context for tracking changes, but</strike> it seems to me the api team added support for patch for a reason, so I'd like to know if the client ought to be invoking the update in a different manner.

#### Update

The link YiDing provided explains how to create a true PATCH request from the client (using the `Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext` created by the `Microsoft.OData.Client 6.2.0` and above.
For convenience, here is the code snippet:

```
var svcContainer = new Default.Container(<svcUri>);
var changeTracker = new DataServiceCollection<Foo>(svcContainer.Foos.Where(f => f.Id == 1));
changeTracker[0].Description = "Patched Description";
svcContainer.SaveChanges();
```

The `DataServiceCollection` implements property tracking, and using this pattern, only the updated properties are sent to the service. 
Without using `DataServiceCollection` and simply using

```
svcContainer.UpdateObject(foo);
svcContainer.SaveChanges();
```

all properties are still sent over the wire despite documentation to the contrary, at least as of `Microsoft.OData.Client 6.7.0`

Comment: When using PATCH amd delta we post only the properties that we want to change in the JSON payload. It looks like you're submitting a full foo object in your sample code?

Comment: @eoghank I've tried several variations of creating an empty instance of the object and setting only the Id and selected property, but (using the auto-generated DataServiceContext) I cannot submit without runtime exceptions of the entity either already being tracked or not being tracked by the client context...

Comment: Have you tried using a different client with json or maybe httpclient? I don't know if the auto generated wcf client proxy supports patch/delta.

Comment: Exactly...my question is specific to the auto-generated client and its derived `DataServiceContext`. I've seen examples using a 'manually' constructed post body.  Again, the example above is from the Web API sample apps on CodePlex posted by the team itself. So, they went through the effort of showing how to use patch versus put, but I was perplexed that the behavior is not as advertised. For large entities, it could be useful to slim the payload for small property updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The client side property tracking is now supported from Microsoft.OData.Client version 6.2.0. It will detect only the modified properties of an entity and send the update request as PATCH instead of PUT to meet the requirement of your scenario. Please refer to this blog post for more details:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/tutorial-sample-client-property-tracking-for-patch/

Comment: This took forever to figure out until I read the linked post. Using a `DataServiceCollection` wrapper is the key here. Without this, the whole entity is always sent.

Comment: It is dissapointing that this didn't get much more focus in the documentation, Patch is a key OData concept. It is possible to do this yourself, but it requires either _heavy_ DTOs with _Self Tracking_ built into the properties of change logic or you need to construct another _Tracking_ context that automatically listens to all property changed events so it knows which properties to send in the patch. You will find `DataServiceCollection` is an elegant lightweight solution to the problem for client side applications that don't do a lot of patching.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller You have no idea how close I got to writing my own library for that.. "Disappointing" is a very, very modest word. `SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties)` throws exceptions unless you wrap your query in a `DataServiceCollection` beforehand. If you do, suddently it starts working. I am baffled, nay, flabbergasted, by the lacking documentation.

Comment: I did write my own library but it ended up being very similar to `DataServiceCollection` in the end. We often start with our own interpretations or implementations in other languages (for me it was angularJS) and try to port it directly into c#. It takes a while to fully appreciate what it is doing and why, it feels like massive overhead to implement properly, but only because we went too far in a different direction to begin with.